# What is the source of electrons and holes in an intrinsic semiconductor?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

In extrinsic semiconductors impurities are added they are the source of electrons/holes. What is the source of electrons and holes in an intrinsic semiconductor.

Comment: Just to see how little research effort you put into this question, I Googled "intrinsic semiconductor" and, the *very first* result has:  *An intrinsic semiconductor is an undoped semiconductor. **This means that holes in the valence band are vacancies created by electrons that have been thermally excited to the conduction band**, as opposed to doped semiconductors where holes or electrons are supplied by a “foreign” atom acting as an impurity.*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is evidence of no prior effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an intrinsic semiconductor electron moves to the conduction band in case of an external disturbance(i.e temperature)..when 1.12eV of energy is given to a si-si bond the bond breaks and generates a hole and an electron.